# VBA checking cell interior color

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do something depending on the interior color of a cell.

This is my code so far but it is showing errors on the If line.

```
For i = 3 To dumpLastRow
With masterFile.Sheets(dumpRef)

    If .Range("A", i).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
            ''''CODE''''
    Else
            ''''CODE''''
    End If

End With
Next
```

If you have any idea it would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: try changing `If .Range("A", i).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then` to `If .Range("A", i).Interior.Color = 4 Then`

Comment: This still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: The error is "error '1004': Application defined or object defined error"

Comment: What shall `.Range("A", i)`be? Where is it documented? Either `.Range("A" & i)` or `.Cells(i, "A")` can be used.

Comment: stupid error, meant change to `If .Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then`

Comment: Have a look at the code posted on here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34805347/loop-through-all-font-colored-cells-in-a-range/34806629#34806629 Hope that helps.

Comment: If the color in question is due to conditional formatting, it is a more robust design to check for the condition which causes the color rather than for the color itself. That way the code doesn't break if the conditional format is tweaked (e.g. to a different shade of blue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as alternative this version might be a bit easier to work with

```
With masterFile.Sheets(dumpRef)
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In .Range("A3:A" & dumpLastRow).Cells

        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
            ''''CODE''''
        Else
            ''''CODE''''
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine letters and numbers like that in range. Use cells instead. You will need to put in cells twice as Range requires that when using `cells` to populate it.
`Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 1)).Interior.ColorIndex`